# When interacting with sqlalchemy in PyDev Console (PyCharm), tables appear empty (but they're not)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm new to Sqlalchemy, so hoping there's a simple explanation for a certain behaviour I'm seeing. When interacting with my database in a script, I'm getting the response as expected, but when I copy the exact same code into the PyDev Console in PyCharm, it is not returning objects from my tables as it thinks they're empty.

If I run the following in a script, I get, as expected, a print out of the table names, a count of 1 for the number of rows and the first name of the first user in my table (`models.User` is my declarative Base users table class).

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
import models

session = Session(create_engine("sqlite:///./database.db"))
print(f"tables are: {engine.table_names()}")  # I know this is deprecated
print(session.query(models.User).count())
print(f"User 1 is {session.query(models.User).first().first_name}")
session.close()
```

returns:

```
>>> tables are: ['users']
>>> 1
>>> User 1 is Chris
```

However, when running the same code in the PyDev Console in PyCharm, I get the table print out as expected (so it sees them), but I get 0 for the row count and of course `session.query(models.User).first()` then returns `None`.

Why does it not see the table contents?

Comment: I wonder if the relative path provided to the database is resolving to different locations. You could try specifying an absolute location for your SQLite database.

Comment: Perhaps, I'll give this a go and report back. Although, if the path was wrong would it not throw an error rather than provide the list of table names and `None` for the user query?

Comment: @Joseph that worked  Thanks for the suggestion. Still odd that it previously worked enough to see the tables but not enough to get stuff from them... Ah well!